# How to convert a scala.xml.Elem into a JsExp in Lift?

Tags: scala, lift

My latest problem is one that I already have a solution for, it just 
feels like there should be a better way.

The problem: 
I want to send a PartialUpdate to a comet service, and I need to XML 
escape the string, so that when it is used on the client it gets the 
correct results. I currently have:

```
override def lowPriority = { 
  case v: List[TaskOwner] => { 
    partialUpdate( 
      taskOwners.foldLeft(JsCrVar("table", Call("$", Str("table#userTable"))) & 
        Call("table.dataTable().fnClearTable"))((r, c) => { 
        r & Call("table.dataTable().fnAddData", 
          JsArray(Str(Text(c.name).toString), 
            Str(Text(c.initials).toString), 
            Str(makeDeleteButton(c).toString)), 
          Num(0)) 
      }) & Call("table.dataTable().fnDraw")) 
  } 
}
```

And this works fine, however the `Str(Text(c.name).toString)` feels 
quite wordy to me. Now, I can, of course, create a pair of implicit 
conversion functions for this, but it seems like this should have 
already been done somewhere, I just don't know where. And so, in the 
spirit of reducing the code that I have written, I ask if anyone knows 
a better way to do this, or if the implicit conversion already exist 
somewhere?

I have seen reference to a [solution here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=D&q=http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/Article-Multi-format-REST-services-with-Lift-td1982057.html). However the code is summarized as:

```
def xmlToJson(xml: Elem): JsExp = { 
  // code to map XML responses to JSON responses.  Handles tricky things like always returning 
  // js arrays for some fields even if only 1 element appears in the XML
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possibly better way of escaping the names is, instead of:

```
JsArray(Str(Text(c.name).toString), 
        Str(Text(c.initials).toString), 
        Str(makeDeleteButton(c).toString))
```

to use

```
JsArray(Str(c.name.asHtml.toString), 
        Str(c.initials.asHtml.toString), 
        Str(makeDeleteButton(c).toString))
```

This can be further reduced by using an implicit within the class like:

```
implicit def elemToJsExp(elem: NodeSeq): JsExp = Str(elem.toString)
…
JsArray(c.name.asHtml,
        c.initials.asHtml,
        makeDeleteButton (c))
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what `Str` does, but maybe you mean `Str(xml.Utility.escape(c.name))`?

Well, how about:

```
def JsStrArray(strings: String*) = JsArray(strings map xml.Utility.escape map Str : _*)
```

And then just use

```
JsStrArray(c.name, c.initials, makeDeleteButton(c).toString)
```

Mmmmm. It might incorrectly escape the result of `makeDeleteButton`. Anyway, you can play with it and see what looks good.

Comment: Str takes a string a "converts" it into a javascript string. I am giving a point for an alternative method, but ideally I would have less verbiage. And Text(String) also xml escapes the string.

Comment: @Paul well, you can `import scala.xml.Utility.escape`, but the point is that this avoids transforming into a `Text` element and then back into a `String`. And you can always use a helper method... Let me put something in the answer.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `JsArray(strings map …`)

Comment: I like the answer, and am tempted to accept it, even though it doesn't really solve my problem, since as you mentioned, it also escapes makeDeleteButton. I have posted the solution that I did use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746849/how-to-convert-a-scala-xml-elem-into-a-jsexp-in-lift/4758244#4758244  Additionally, in my case, c.name is not actually a string, but a TypedMapper, although there might be an implicit conversion to string somewhere.

Comment: @Paul Sure, it was just a typo.